# How do I solve a system of equations with Eulers Method?

Tags: python, numpy, physics, numerical-methods, ode

So I have one problem for motion. The problem is finding for which angle, a object would fall off a sphere. Suppose the sphere is frictionless and all that, so it just slides off. Logically this would say that when the normal force acting on the object is 0, the object leaves the surface. So when the normal force is 0, the object has travelled an angle from the start. At what point does it leave? Well analytically it was simple to find the answer, it is arccos(2/3*cos(startingposition)). Right now I'm trying to find this numerically. It requires a system of equations that solve themselves basically, because all i have is just inital conditions, while the rest is just differential equations, so I'm implementing a form for Eulers method in a for-loop. So for what angle value is N equal to zero is what im trying to find, but all my numbers are just weird. My code below:

```
g=9.8 
m=0.2 #mass of object
R=0.5 #radius of the circle that its sliding down from
r=0.07 #radius of the object sliding down 
grad = 180/np.pi #turn radiens to degrees


theta=np.zeros(91) #thetas
N = np.zeros(91) #normal force
w = np.zeros(91) #omega
a = np.zeros(91) #tangential acceleration
v = np.zeros(91) #speed

def eulersMethod():

    dt=0.01 #small timestep

    thetai=[np.radians(0)] #startangle theta (where on the circle do i let it slide from start angle 0 degrees)

    a[0]=g*np.sin(thetai[0]) #initial condition for acceleration
    v[0]=0 #initial condition for velocity (starts at rest)
    w[0]=(v[0]/(R+r)) #initial condition for angular velocity
    N[0]=m*g*np.cos(thetai[0]) #initial condition for normal force
    theta[0]=np.radians(0) #initial angle which is 0 degrees
    
    for i in range(0,90): 
        v[i+1]=v[i]+a[i]*dt #v=v+at (Eulers method)

        w[i+1]=v[i+1]/(R+r) #omega=v/r

        theta[i+1]=theta[i]+w[i]*dt #0(t+dt)=0(t)+(d0/dt)*dt (Eulers method) finding theta iteratively

        N[i+1]=(m*g*np.cos(theta[i+1]))-(m/(R+r)*(v[i+1])**2) #N=mgcos(theta)-mv^2/r

        a[i+1]=g*np.sin(np.radians(theta[i+1])) #a=gsin(theta)

        print(v[i])
        
        
    theta_falloff=[] #where will the object fall off?
    
    for i in N:
        if i==0: #for the i-th element that is equal to zero (N=0), then append that theta value to a list
            theta_falloff.append(theta[i])

    return theta_falloff
```

For the velocity I'm getting weird numbers like:

```
[0.         0.         0.00268639 0.00537278 0.00805925 0.01074589
 0.01343279 0.01612002 0.01880768 0.02149584 0.0241846  0.02687403
 0.02956422 0.03225525 0.03494721 0.03764019 0.04033427 0.04302953
 0.04572606 0.04842394 0.05112325 0.05382409 0.05652654 0.05923068
 0.0619366  0.06464437 0.0673541  0.07006586 0.07277973 0.07549581
 0.07821417 0.08093491 0.08365811 0.08638385 0.08911222 0.0918433
 0.09457719 0.09731397 0.10005371 0.10279652 0.10554247 0.10829166
 0.11104416 0.11380006 0.11655946 0.11932243 0.12208907 0.12485945
 0.12763368 0.13041183 0.13319399 0.13598026 0.13877071 0.14156543
 0.14436452 0.14716805 0.14997613 0.15278883 0.15560624 0.15842846
 0.16125557 0.16408765 0.16692481 0.16976713 0.17261469 0.17546759
 0.17832592 0.18118976 0.1840592  0.18693434 0.18981527 0.19270208
 0.19559485 0.19849367 0.20139865 0.20430986 0.20722741 0.21015138
 0.21308186 0.21601895 0.21896273 0.22191331 0.22487077 0.2278352
 0.2308067  0.23378537 0.23677128 0.23976455 0.24276526 0.24577351
 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.00268639 0.00537278 0.00805925 0.01074589
 0.01343279 0.01612002 0.01880768 0.02149584 0.0241846  0.02687403
 0.02956422 0.03225525 0.03494721 0.03764019 0.04033427 0.04302953
 0.04572606 0.04842394 0.05112325 0.05382409 0.05652654 0.05923068
 0.0619366  0.06464437 0.0673541  0.07006586 0.07277973 0.07549581
 0.07821417 0.08093491 0.08365811 0.08638385 0.08911222 0.0918433
 0.09457719 0.09731397 0.10005371 0.10279652 0.10554247 0.10829166
 0.11104416 0.11380006 0.11655946 0.11932243 0.12208907 0.12485945
 0.12763368 0.13041183 0.13319399 0.13598026 0.13877071 0.14156543
 0.14436452 0.14716805 0.14997613 0.15278883 0.15560624 0.15842846
 0.16125557 0.16408765 0.16692481 0.16976713 0.17261469 0.17546759
 0.17832592 0.18118976 0.1840592  0.18693434 0.18981527 0.19270208
 0.19559485 0.19849367 0.20139865 0.20430986 0.20722741 0.21015138
 0.21308186 0.21601895 0.21896273 0.22191331 0.22487077 0.2278352
 0.2308067  0.23378537 0.23677128 0.23976455 0.24276526 0.24577351
 0.24878938]
```

Comment: can you please include where you define `g`, `m`, `a`, `v`, `w`, `N`, `theta`?

Comment: There, it is essentially just empty numpy arrays zeros

Comment: Issue might have to do with the conversion to radians in `a[i+1]=g*np.sin(np.radians(theta[i+1]))`. Is theta not already radians?

Comment: nope, still wrong